# Delay to read barcodes after starting camera in Zxing?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm facing a problem with the barcode scanner from zxing library for android. Actually, the scanner works fine, but sometimes it's so fast that the user doesn't have time to position the camera so it gets all the barcode, and then the barcode is read partially.I want to know if there is a way to, after starting the camera,have a delay until the first reading. Here is a piece of my code:

```
public class Produto extends AppCompatActivity {
private IntentIntegrator qrScan;
private Button btnCodBarras;
private Button btnEnviar;
private Button btnExcluir;
private EditText nomeCliente;
private ListView listaProdutos;
private ArrayList<String> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
private MyCustomAdapter adapter;
private SharedPreferences settings;

private String nome;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_produto);

    configScan();

    btnCodBarras = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCodBarras);
    btnEnviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
    listaProdutos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaProdutos);
    nomeCliente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cliente);

    adapter=new MyCustomAdapter(produtos,getApplicationContext(),listaProdutos);

    listaProdutos.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnCodBarras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            qrScan.initiateScan();
        }
    });
```

I'm just calling via intent. And I can't seem to be able to modify IntentIntegrator.java and the other zxing files.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about adding a short delay in `onClick()` before calling `qrScan.initiateScan();`

Comment: Didn't work. It just delayed BEFORE the camera starts...

Comment: Then try reading the camera output for a short time and throwing it away.  Only after that start processing the output looking for barcodes.